# how can a webpage determine if a user has mouse or touchscreen input?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, hardware

If I have a webpage coded in html5 and javascript how can it detect what kind of input hardware the user has ?
To give useful and correct instructions to them.
A user may have mouse, touchscreen, both or full keyboard, limited keyboard on Smartphone ...etc.

Comment: You can use Modernizr and detect whether touch events are supported.

Comment: @Pointy: That won't help much.

Comment: @SLaks well it'll do what it does. The question is of course somewhat misguided.

Comment: Relevant? http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/

Comment: Testing for touch support is pretty trivial (search for it, you'll get thousands of results), why do you need to know? You can usuallly provide instructions in neutral terms, e.g. "*select*" rather than "*click"*.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to avoid mouseover effects when I'm not sure.

```
    <script>
    var hasMouse = false;

    window.document.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseFound);

        function mouseFound() {
            hasMouse = true;
            window.document.removeEventListener('mouseover', mouseFound);
            console.log('found a mouse');
        }
    </script>
```